# What is more effective, microdata or JSON-LD?

Tags: google, markup, knowledge-graph, google-my-business, google+

I know that Google prefers JSON-LD over microdata, that is a given. I intend to use both as much as I can. I also know that the Earth rotates around Google and the Sun is just a moon. However, from a performance perspective, which is more effective overall (I assume microdata) and is JSON-LD a requirement for things like Google+, Google Maps, and Google My Business? I am hoping that this question would be a semi-authoritative update on the topic of encouraging knowledge graph cards and any offering Bing might have. If there are any other requirements besides mark-up, that would help as a side-note.

I have created a fairly simple one-page mobile-first website which I intend to expand later with content for renters and landlords as well as comments on rental real-estate law and tricks of the trade. I intend to use Google My Business and Google Maps as much as possible for validation and ranking. I will not be using HTTPS. The domain name will have a private registration. I want to build my trust metrics to compensate for these factors.

I ask these questions because it seems that mark-up has changed somewhat lately and how people use them as well as how the SEs see them. I do want to encourage a knowledge graph card right out of the box. I do have rental listings online now and doing a search for the address does result in some major real-estate rental sites having a listing as a result of past advertising. I expect/hope that Google will see this as validation. Who knows?

I am just dotting my t's and crossing my i's and seeing if there is an official word out there on the subject.

Comment: Right now there is no any difference, [but in future Google might launch new snippet that is only implemented by JSON LD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gS4_JH-QqSg), hence they recommended to use JSON LD, because they sure about it, and it does not depend on other organization.

Answer (score 1):

- Google doesn't `prefer` JSON-LD over microdata. Google just offers its documentation more for those, who automate website building and maintenance. There is no effectivity in terms of what kind of markup gives you `better` rich snippets.
- But, dependently of your webmaster workflows, JSON-LD should be more effective in terms of daily maintenance: creation and injection of JSON-LD can be automated, microdata can't (technically it can for sure, but with such affort, that it makes the whole procedure no longer cost-efficient).
- In terms of website performance JSON-LD wins too - it produces less code and can be implemented on the end of HTML document. To do so with microdata is possible too, but it is much more tricky and not clean.
- To learn structured data i would rather recommend to use microdata - it is more illustrative.